# How to send request and get response from localhost in c#

Tags: c#, http

I have installed "vivekn sentimental tool" which is running in my local host.when we send an http request using unirest post method to the server which contains a string it sends response whether it is positive or negative.I had used it in java.but anyone tell me how to use that in c#

here is my java code

```
HttpResponse request = Unirest.post("http:localhost:1681/api/text/")
    .header("X-Mashape-Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxx")
    .field("txt", "i like icecream").asJson();
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(request.getBody().toString());
Object ob = js.get("result");
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(ob.ToString);
String sentiment = (String)job.get("sentiment");
```

what I need is I want to send a request to the localhost and receive a response which is json with or without using unirest

Comment: What have you tried in C# and could you explain why that might not have worked?

Comment: I didnt try anything in c# @Default...

Answer (score 0):

It's going to roughly look something like this:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add(
            "X-Mashape-Authorization", "1R1tvmPFLFL7brrvfO9jvsqnvhiVggAn");
    var body = wc.DownloadString("http:localhost:1681/api/text/");
    var js = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(body);
    /* do something with the json */
}
```

You'll need to get the `Newtonsoft` library from NuGet - ID: "Newtonsoft.Json".

Comment: but I have passed a string "I like icecream" which is the input for that localhost...But u didn't include it in ur code...May i know how to include that..@Enigmativity

Comment: @Reddevil - Like I said, roughly like my code. I don't know what you Java library does so I couldn't give you a better answer. Good luck.